# Multiple file upload Error cannot call a method on a null-valued expression powershell script by Phil Childs

Tags: powershell

I am using this script 
http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html
the script

```
                function Copy-FilestoSP
            {
                Param (
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LocalPath, 
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SiteUrl, 
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Library, 
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$LibraryStartFolder, 
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$ManifestFilePath, 
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$IncludeSubFolders,
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Approve,
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$CheckIn,
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Overwrite,
                       [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$FlattenStructure
                       )

                try
                {

                #Get web and document library objects
                $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
                $docLibrary = $web.Lists[$Library]
                ---code skipped-----
```

When I debugged I found that after Get-SPWeb I am getting

```
                You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
            At E:\BH\utility\Get-SPScripts.Copy-FilesToSP.ps1:331 char:21
            +         $web.Dispose <<<< ()
                + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dispose:String) [], RuntimeException
                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

And at 331 its $web.Dispose()

```
        catch [System.SystemException]
            { 
                write-host "The script has stopped because there has been an error.  "$_.Message
            }
            finally
            {
                $web.Dispose()
            }
            }
            write-host "SharePoint 2010 Multiple File Upload Script - Get-SPScripts.com"
```

I am executing it like this

```
Copy-FilestoSP -LocalPath "E:\files" -SiteUrl "http://sp2010" -Library "myDocuments"
```

Comment: `$web.Dispose()` -> `if($null-ne$web){$web.Dispose()}`

Comment: Now I get just
`The script has stopped because there has been an error.  `